# ROS Answers SE migration: Using Webui

Tags: ros, turtlebot, teleoperation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have recently been trying to interface turtlebot with Webui packages to create some telepresence over a internet web browser. I was able to get everything installed and working, but I can only launch apps under localhost only and not through my external ip. I believe my network is configured properly through port forwarding. As I can load the gui from the internet and read some information about roscore. But I can only see nodes, and topics under localhost. Is this normal operation with Webui? I understand the stack maybe deprecated or no longer under development. But I was hoping to get some help on this issue. My main goal is to get a web interface similar to Roborealm's where I can control turtlebot and broadcast video over the internet. Any Ideas appreciated....

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12200/using-webui.../) by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on ROS Answers with karma: 458 on 2011-12-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-12-05**:
Thanks for the reply dlaz.. I did notice some errors in apache logs but nothing related to the problems I was seeing. I actually figured out what my problem was, see my answer. I hope this helps anyone trying to utilize Webui...

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-12-04**:
Are you seeing any errors anywhere? In particular, is anything showing up in the apache logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The problem I was encountering was due to admin privilege's associated with the ubuntu group user. I also have come to find out thanks to a helpful friend of mine ,Thanx Jay... that the apache server is some what secured and that admin privaleges are not given to non-local users. So  we did some research and found a helpful command that sets the user {www-data} to admin status. Thus allowing me to launch apps from an external ip. I also understand that this may compromise my security on the server which is why it isnt a default setting to begin with. So to correct my initial issue.. First run roscore, webui.launch and type in terminal 'sudo adduser www-data admin ' then restart the server and possibly roscore and that should do the trick. Im not sure how this may or may not work for others using different versions of ubuntu but I'm using 10.10 and worked like a charm.

---

Originally posted by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) with karma: 458 on 2011-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Atom](https://answers.ros.org/users/636/atom/) on 2011-12-06**:
Also like to add in your routers configuration for port forwarding make sure you have ports 9090 and 8068 assigned to your computers ip.